# null as instance of a type parameter

Tags: scala, generics, null, type-parameter

Ok, I know better than to use nulls as a design choice, but in this case I have to. Why the following does not compile?

```
def test[T<:AnyRef](o :Option[T]) :T = o getOrElse null

Error:(19, 53) type mismatch;
               found   : Null(null)
               required: T
               Note: implicit method foreignKeyType is not applicable here because it comes  after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
def test[T<:AnyRef](o :Option[T]) :T = o getOrElse null
                                                   ^
```

Comment: why don't you use `Option.orNull`?

Comment: It was my first choice, but when it didn't work (for reason given in the answer below) I tried to make the the example simpler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Null is a subtype of all reference types, but the fact that T is a subtype of AnyRef doesn't guarantee that T is a reference type -- in particular, Nothing is a subtype of AnyRef which does not contain null.

Your code Works if you add a lower bound:

```
def test[T >:Null <:AnyRef](o :Option[T]) :T = o getOrElse null;
```

It works:

```
scala> def test[T >:Null <:AnyRef](o :Option[T]) :T = o getOrElse null;
test: [T >: Null <: AnyRef](o: Option[T])T

scala> 

scala> 

scala> test(None)
res0: Null = null

scala> test(Some(Some))
res1: Some.type = Some
```

Comment: The lower bound is needed because `Nothing <: Null`. Otherwise, you could create an instance of `Nothing` using `test[Nothing](None)`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why this does not work - `Null` is a subtype of all reference types in Scala, so you would expect that this would work with any `T <: AnyRef`. You can make it work with `asInstanceOf`:

```
def test[T <: AnyRef](o: Option[T]): T = o getOrElse null.asInstanceOf[T]
```

(Try to avoid using `null` whenever possible in Scala - I can imagine you'd have a legitimate use case, for example when you need to pass data to Java code).

By the way, `Option` has a method `orNull` which will return the value of an option if it is a `Some` and `null` if it is `None`.

Comment: This will NPE if called with parameter None.

Comment: In the REPL, but that might be a side-effect of the REPL. Try this in the REPL: `test(None: Option[String])`

Comment: You're right. Still, the solution of using >:Null instead of <:AnyRef (which is equivalent, because all reference types fall in between these two) is cleaner than using .asInstanceOf.