# How to assign null to an element of an array of type Ordered[A] in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have for the last half an hour been fighting to get the following code to work:

```
class X[A <% Ordered[A]] {
  var x : A = null
}
```

I understand that `A` can extend `AnyVal` instead of `AnyRef`, so I'd be perfectly fine with a solution like

```
class X[A <% Ordered[A] with AnyRef] {
  var x : A = null
}
```

but that also doesn't seem to work.

How should I go about this? I don't want to use options here.

---

EDIT:
What I'm really after is for a way to do this:

```
class X[A <% Ordered[A]] {
  val array : Array[A] = ...
  array(0) = null
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [null as instance of a type parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27399205/null-as-instance-of-a-type-parameter)

Comment: The answer to the other question also explains why `<: AnyRef` doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a lower bound `>: Null` to the type. That means that [`Null`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/#scala.Null) is the subtype of `A`, and thus `A` can take `null` as its value:

```
class X[A >: Null <% Ordered[A]] {
  var x : A = null
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for array elements: array(0) = _ gives a compilation error.

Comment: @devouredelysium It works for your updated question as is.

Answer (score 3):

You can write:

```
class X[A <% Ordered[A]] {
  var x : A = _
}
```

this gets you whatever the default value for A is:

```
scala> (new X[Int]).x
res0: Int = 0

scala> (new X[Double]).x
res1: Double = 0.0

scala> (new X[String]).x
res2: String = null
```

Not sure if this suits your use case; see also Kolmar's answer.

Comment: Had completely forgot about `_`. Who uses vars anyways? :)

Comment: Hello. That doesn't seem to work with array elements (that's actually my use case).

Comment: `Array.ofDim` makes an array that's initialized with the default value for the type.

Comment: P.S. You should probably just open a new question, as what you're asking for now is almost entirely different from your original question.